# Implementing Rails' layout functionality with Apache Tiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, tiles, layout

Has anybody tried duplicating Ruby on Rails' layout functionality with Apache Tiles 2 ? I'm trying to integrate Tiles 2 with Spring.  I have a previously written custom view resolver for the Spring framework that does this quite nicely, but I'm upgrading to Spring Webflow 2 and I need to be able to integrate Tiles 2

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly this.  Here's some snippets from that Java app.

```
<definition name="registration" template="/tiles/layouts/defaultLayout.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="body" value="undefined" />
  <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/footer.jsp?alt=true" />
</definition>

<definition name="site.signup" extends="registration">
  <put-attribute name="page" value="Signup" />
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/common/signup.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Something like that worked for us.  It's been a while (I've fled to the Ruby world) so I couldn't honestly actually explain what any of that actually means.

Comment: Hi Otto,

Thank you for your response, I guess I should have been a bit more clear in my question : I'm looking for a solution that's convention-based.  I already wound up moving to the same solution you've presented, but it's very verbose and requires explicit definition of all of the views.